# iOS How do I remove glow/shadow from UISlider

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

How do I remove the glow/shadow from this UISlider?

[image: glow ghost]

Answer (score 7):

It turns out, all I needed to do was set a custom thumb image and the shadow doesn't exist.

Comment: Would be really helpful to post "how" you did it? Did you create just any random image and used it as thumb image or were you somehow access the system thumb image but without shadow?

Answer (score 2):

I do this in the `didSet` of the `UISlider` (Swift 3):

```
@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!{
    didSet{
        slider.setThumbImage(<image when not touched>, for: .normal)
        slider.setThumbImage(<image when touched>, for: .highlighted)
    }
}
```