# How to remove the shadow around the thumb of UISlider

Tags: ios, uiview, slider

[image]

I'd like to remove the shadow on the thumb of the slider without having to replace the image of the thumb entirely. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you found anything to remove the `UISlider`'s thumb image shadow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS How do I remove glow/shadow from UISlider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805151/ios-how-do-i-remove-glow-shadow-from-uislider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `UISlider`s `thumbTintColor` does the trick.

[edit] It seems to have shadow color the same as is the tint one and there seems to be no border..